# StringComparer.CurrentCulture Case-Insensitive

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, .net-7.0

Both `StringComparer.CurrentCulture` and `StringComparer.InvariantCulture` appear case-insensitive.  Is there a way to control that?  StringComparer.Ordinal is case-sensitive, as expected.

Note: all three comparers also have an `IgnoreCase` version, which I am *not* using.

Code:

```
var comparers = new List<StringComparer>{StringComparer.CurrentCulture, StringComparer.InvariantCulture, StringComparer.Ordinal};

foreach (var c in comparers)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine($"A B {c.Compare("A", "B")}");
    Console.Out.WriteLine($"A b {c.Compare("A", "b")}");
    Console.Out.WriteLine($"a B {c.Compare("a", "B")}");
}
```

Output:

```
A B -1
A b -1
a B -1
A B -1
A b -1
a B -1
A B -1
A b -33
a B 31
```

I would expect the 2nd and 3rd lines and 5th and 6th lines to be different.

Comment: Why do you think they are case-insensitive? Try comparing "A" and "a", are you getting a zero?

Comment: Case insensitivity only deals with equivalence checks. You're wondering about unicode collation which is a [very fun topic on its own](https://unicode.org/reports/tr10). 9.6 is probably interesting. It seems to be that the sort order is `a,A,b,B` for `en-us` and the invariant culture. For ordinals there's no big surprise - that's just comparing the codepoints where upper case letters come before lower case. Surprising on first glance, but I can see the logic when considering other characters that don't fall into the upper/lower case distinction.

Comment: And I imagine there's no case insensitive collation algorithm, because it'd probably be impossible to define a total order if you tried to do that, given all the complexities of unicode comparisons. And without those properties you couldn't use it for actual sorting anything, which would make it rather useless.